# why data is getting inserted into table even if my oracle form status is in query mode

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have a programming unit which inserts data to a table T1.
When i open the form and press the save button without making any changes to form (status ofform in query mode) duplicate values are inserted to form.
Is there any way to stop inserting this duplicates

Answer (score 0):

Saying that "status of form is in query mode", I presume that you entered query mode (so that form waits for you to enter search criteria and execute query).

You can't do anything in query mode but execute (or cancel) query.

Save button is **disabled** in query mode:

[image]

so - what do you mean by saying that "you open the form and press the save button (...) (status of form in query mode)? You **can not** press the "Save" button in query mode.

---

Anyway: you should prevent duplicates to be inserted.

If you let the database do it for you, create **unique index** (or unique constraint or primary key constraint) - Oracle will then raise an error, saying that you violated uniqueness.

Alternatively, do it in the trigger, using `NOT EXISTS` that specifies unique columns in `WHERE` clause, e.g.

```
insert into your_table
  (id, name, address, social_security_number)
  select :BLK_ID, :BLK.NAME, :BLK.ADDRESS, :BLK.SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER
  from dual
  where not exists (select null
                    from your_table
                    where social_security_number = :BLK.SOCIAL_SECURITY_NUMBER);
```

If such a value already exist, `INSERT` won't fail, but it'll insert 0 rows.